# ScrollBar Issue

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, stylesheet

I want to create a Custom Scroll bar in my FLEX 3.0 application. Which should enable to use Text instead of |||| that shows in ScrollThumb...

I have used mx_internal for changing the style of that but still facing the problem that text is not displayed. here is the code that i have created.

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;

use namespace mx_internal;

public function onInit():void
{
    scrollbar.scrollThumb.iconName = "";
    scrollbar.scrollThumb.labelPlacement = "left";
    var str:String = (scrollbar.scrollPosition+1).toString() + "/" + (scrollbar.maxScrollPosition+1).toString();
    scrollbar.scrollThumb.label = str;
}

<mx:HScrollBar id="scrollbar" width="100%" pageSize="1" styleName="customScrollBar" />
```

Here is the stylesheet for that

```
.customScrollBar
{
    up-arrow-skin: ClassReference(null);
    down-arrow-skin: ClassReference(null);
}
```

Here I am giving you the sample image that kind of scroll bar i want to create.

[image]

Please Help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a custom ThumbSkin Class.

Then, assign that as a classReference in the CSS.

To learn how to create these custom skins, read these two Adobe documents.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinning_7.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinning_5.html

To get the paging data into the scrollbar, you will have to calculate the paging data on the main context, and then just pass in the paging info as a String to the thumbskin with a label.  The scroller and thumb itself will not be able to know how many pages it is on, or how many items are being displayed.  However, if you wanted a percerntage, that could be done in the scroller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i don't know how to create custom ThumbSkin Class and if page changes i need to change the text of scrollThumb to 3/5 or 4/5 etc.. for that i need to change in mx_internal any idea for that? if possible provide any link...

Comment: hi thanks for the link but still facing an issue that how to embed the TEXT in scrollThumb.

Comment: @SagarRawal can you update your code with how you are tying to get the text in and what isn't working?

Comment: in the onInit function i have changed the mx_internal roperties of scrollThumb and i have to change as per the scroll in the "scrollbar.scrollThumb.label" property.. so please help me...

Comment: "mx_internal" sounds like a stolen decompiled app

Comment: @The_asMan very often you need to access mx_internal to get to properties which are otherwise not accessible.  This is especially true with TextField.